# post__in select all custom posts and not the selected array of ids

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, array

In order to add a personilized sidebar for costom posts I define a shortcode using add_shortcode ( >name shortcode< ) and I recall the shortcode in sidebar using a plugin.
In the sidebar I must show a second menu under the first for some specific custom post type. So I define a $sidebar for all custom posts and write the following code to select some specific custom posts to add the second menu to them:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post',
        'post__in' => array( >custom post ids separeted by comma< )
    );
    
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    
    $sidebar = $logo.$menu.$box;
    
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        $sidebar = $sidebar.$menu1.$box1;
    }
    
    $out = null;

    return $sidebar;
```

The problem is that the code add the second menu to **all** custom posts and not only on the array of costom post ids.
What's wrong?

Comment: Please include the function name, and where/how the function is called.

Comment: I define a shortcode using add_shortcode ( >name shortcode< ) and I recall the shortcode in sidebar using a plugin

Comment: Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Where/how are you building the array of posts for 'posts__in'?  Are we certain that it's giving the correct information.